# How to Remove Hyperlink underline in Gmail while sending Email template from outlook

Tags: css, html, email, outlook

Today have faced a new issue while sending mail from outlook to Gmail.The issue is Hyperlink element is showing as underline.
I have tried below.

**Method 1:**

```
 <td  width="500px" align="center" style=" text-align: left; font-size:1.2em; font-family:Candara; color: #FFFFFF;">
             <a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">info@xxx.com</a>      
    </td>
```

method 2:

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none !important;" target="_blank">info@ccc.com</a>
```

method 3:

```
  a {text-decoration: none !important; color: #000; cursor: text;}
```

This code is working fine in browser,outlook and the problem is in Gmail mailbox.Because of Gmail appending span tag after the hyperlink tag dynamically.

I have attached a video reference here:

http://recordit.co/OGlkkBiXGX

Given: text-decoration none its not taken by gmail box because of after a tag inside span tag gets added .

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>mailtest</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <table width="582" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background:black;">
            <tr> 
                <td  width="500px" align="center" style=" text-align: left; font-size:1.2em; font-family:Candara; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <img style="margin-left:10px;" src="http://codestrz.com/Content/mail/envelope.png" alt="" border="0" height="18" width="18"/> 
                    <a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">info@xxx.com</a>      
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried for this  simple  tag :

```
    <p style="color:white;"> EXTRANET.EXAMPLE.COM</p>
```

Afterwards tried for simple p tag without link,

Output in outlook 2013[image]:

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

gmail output
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what the code looks like with the appended `<span>`?

Comment: Kindly look through video mentioned above it will show clearly

Comment: what is your outlook version?

Comment: @Narendhran outlook 2013

Comment: <div class="myClass">
        <a href="mailto:info@example.com"> info@xxx.com<span class=myClass1> info@ccc.com </span></a>
</div>       then in your css,  .myClass,.myClass1{ text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; }

Comment: @narendran i have tried already , now again tried see the screencast here http://recordit.co/iAD6BPK7pW

Answer (score 0):

Insert `;` after text-decoration:none in your styling because html in some situation not read correct css without end.

Comment: sorry for my typo , nothing works because of span tag append dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
 <a href='yourLink' bgcolor="#000000">yourLinkHere</a>
```

*or*

```
<a href="yourLink" style="color:#CCCCCC; text-decoration:none;"><color="#CCCCCC">yourLink</font></a>
```

**For outlook version above 2007,**

- press CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S
- Right click on the Hyperlink entry in the Styles and Formatting pane and select Modify
- Change the font settings for your hyperlink. (remove underline)

Thats it,
**To change it for all new messages that you create**

- enable the option(radio button): New documents based on this template

Comment: @Narendran I had tried not working , and also chosen the hyperlink and remove the underline its working inside outlook,after receive the mail in gmail i am getting underline for the text.

Comment: Not working above code ,if you have interested try it in your outlook to send mail with gmail.what exactly happen there to understand better.  http://recordit.co/iAD6BPK7pW