# Remove Underline From Links on Emails Sent from Outlook to Gmail

Tags: email, templates, outlook, gmail, mjml

I'm struggling to find a solution to remove the blue underline from Links on Emails Sent from Outlook (Outlook for Office 365) to Gmail (Desktop version)

The generated html works perfectly on Google Chrome, but not on Gmail

Here is the whole Code of my tests:
It was generated with mjml framework:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    table,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    p {
      display: block;
      margin: 13px 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if mso]>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte mso 11]>
        <style type="text/css">
          .mj-outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->

  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
      .mj-column-per-100 {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- Override Gmail blue links  
    -->
    .ii
    a[href]
    {
    text-decoration:
    none;
    color:
    inherit
     !important;
    }
    .link-nostyle
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    none
    }
    .link-underlined
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    underline
     !important;
    }
    .link-not-underlined
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    text-decoration-color:
    transparent;
    color:
    green;
    }
    .myClass,
    .myClass1
    {
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    color:
    orange;
    ;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
      <table
         align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
      >
        <tr>
          <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
      <![endif]-->
    <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                
        <tr>
      
            <td
               class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
            >
          <![endif]-->
              <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:20px;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:#F45e46;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-nostyle" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">Hello World</a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo odio impedit minus suscipit, quis autem nulla aliquam maxime optio facere, esse quia corrupti possimus expedita aspernatur modi molestiae, iusto dolore. <a style="text-decoration: underline !important; color: orange !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: underline !important; color: red !important;">Test link 2</span></a>
                        <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #00d0ff !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: green !important;">Test link 2</span></a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Link underlined -->
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-underlined" style="color: #f5b33c; text-decoration: underline !important;"><span style="text-decoration: underline !important;">link underlined</span></a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Link NOT underlined -->
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-not-underlined">link not underlined</a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;"><a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #00d0ff !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: green !important;">Test link 3</span></a>
                        <br><br> lorem Ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color: red !important; text-decoration:none !important;">
                          <span style="color:red !important; text-decoration:none!important;">Getting Started with Our Services</span>
                        </a>
                        <br><br>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC; text-decoration:none;">
                          <color="#cccccc">test 4 </color="#cccccc">
                        </a>
                        <div class="myClass"> <a href="mailto:info@example.com">
                            <span class="myClass1">info@ccc.com </span></a> </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Test for numbers: 0711 12345678</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if mso | IE]>
            </td>
          
        </tr>
      
                  </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried the whole propositions from this post:
[How to Remove Hyperlink underline in Gmail while sending Email template from outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946034/how-to-remove-hyperlink-underline-in-gmail-while-sending-email-template-from-out) without success

Comment: Gmail site does a lot of stripping os CSS.  You can probably get it to work, but then it might look goofy in other apps.  https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-fix-blue-links-in-gmail

Comment: Sending HTML email from an email client (Outlook, Gmail, etc.) is usually problematic. Each client is prone to change the HTML in their own "special" way. You might consider using an Email Service Provider for sending the email; you can find one that doesn't ever change your HTML. (And of course, you can compare the HTML you receive from the ESP against what you asked them to send.) You can send a free test of your email through putsmail.com (don't use the option to inline CSS). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

All those links with `underline` are having an inline css for displaying underline so that's why it's still visible. And at some places `anchor` tags are having `span` as children with `underline` css, so although the `text-decoration: none` is set for the `anchor` tags its not working because of the `span` inside. I have removed that from the code and replaced it below. Please refer below for the same. Hope this solves the issue

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    table,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    p {
      display: block;
      margin: 13px 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if mso]>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte mso 11]>
        <style type="text/css">
          .mj-outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->

  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
      .mj-column-per-100 {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- Override Gmail blue links  
    -->
    .ii
    a[href]
    {
    text-decoration:
    none;
    color:
    inherit
     !important;
    }
    .link-nostyle
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    none
    }
    .link-underlined
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    }
    .link-underlined span {
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    }
    .link-not-underlined
    {
    color:
    inherit;
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    text-decoration-color:
    transparent;
    color:
    green;
    }
    .myClass a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    .myClass,
    .myClass1
    {
    text-decoration:
    none
     !important;
    color:
    orange;
    ;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
      <table
         align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
      >
        <tr>
          <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
      <![endif]-->
    <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                
        <tr>
      
            <td
               class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
            >
          <![endif]-->
              <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:20px;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:#F45e46;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-nostyle" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">Hello World</a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo odio impedit minus suscipit, quis autem nulla aliquam maxime optio facere, esse quia corrupti possimus expedita aspernatur modi molestiae, iusto dolore. <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: orange !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: red !important;">Test link 2</span></a>
                        <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #00d0ff !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: green !important;">Test link 2</span></a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Link underlined -->
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-underlined" style="color: #f5b33c; text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="text-decoration: none !important;">link underlined</span></a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Link NOT underlined -->
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">Hello <a href="https://mjml.io" class="link-not-underlined">link not underlined</a></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;"><a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #00d0ff !important;" href="https://www.google.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important; color: green !important;">Test link 3</span></a>
                        <br><br> lorem Ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color: red !important; text-decoration:none !important;">
                          <span style="color:red !important; text-decoration:none!important;">Getting Started with Our Services</span>
                        </a>
                        <br><br>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC; text-decoration:none;">
                          <color="#cccccc">test 4 </color="#cccccc">
                        </a>
                        <div class="myClass"> <a href="mailto:info@example.com">
                            <span class="myClass1">info@ccc.com </span></a> </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">Test for numbers: 0711 12345678</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if mso | IE]>
            </td>
          
        </tr>
      
                  </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this shows always the blue underlines under Gmail / Desktop version (When the Email is sent from Outlook)

Comment: Oh. In think [link](https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-fix-blue-links-in-gmail) there is some solution which is being mentioned under `OVERRIDE ALL LINK STYLING`. Not sure whether this will work or not but may be you can try that.

Comment: One thing I observed is that at least in Gmail web there's no inline css provided for `underline`. Also in the above code can you try providing `!importanat` to all the inline css properties wherever `text-decoration` attribute is provided.